# Does "least two weeks to complete" mean it will be done in 2 weeks or more than 2 weeks?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> We are in the process of updating your account. These updates take at least two weeks to complete.

Please clarify this... does this mean that it will be done in 2 weeks or 2 week or more ?

Answer (score 1):

From Merriam-Webster's definition of [least](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/least):

> **at least**
>   **1** : at the minimum
>   // at least once a week

In other words, if you say *at least* two weeks, you mean that it will not take *less than* two weeks.

But you haven't said anything about it not taking more time—so that's still a possibility.

So, when you say *at least two weeks*, you mean two weeks or more.

Comment: Grammatically, I agree with you. Practically, though, language like this is often used to temper expectations. I’ve had websites told me to expect an email in 20 minutes when it arrived in less than five; I’ve had IT support folks tell me it would take two days to create an account and it was done in only an hour. In the OP’s example, I wouldn’t be surprised to find out the account was updated in less than a week.

Comment: @J.R. As I understand it, Scotty from *Star Trek* always doubled every estimate of time for engine repair so he'd end up looking like a genius. ;)